# Coldfusion.Ajax.submitForm error

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I have a site that uses AJAX almost exclusively to read and post data.  While just leaving the page sitting for a while, without clicking around, I'll get the following error:

```
error 12031: ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm: Error submitting form, id: nForm.
```

`nForm` is one of the form names, but it seems to happen to some others as well.

This seems to only happen in Internet Explorer, but I can't confirm that.  Does this have to do with simultaneous calls to the database?  Do I change something up in the ColdFusion administrator setting?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: Are you leaving your page sitting around long enough for your session to time out?

Answer (score 1):

When given the choice in libraries to do AJAX with, you could use jQuery, from a group of people that have focused on making sure everything is cross-browser compatible, tests thoroughly, and fixes bugs; or you could use the built in library from Adobe who have always written poor, bug riddled client side code and have about the worst track record of fixing bugs that don't immediately affect their bottom line.

I love CF, but wouldn't touch that ajax library with a ten foot pole. Switch over to jQuery 1.9.x. It's better documented, better written, and there is a much broader range of developers that can help you with it when you have problems.

Comment: I agree with the answer above.  jQuery often creates a much 'lighter' version of your pages.  What I mean by that is that there will not be 10~20 lines of extra scripts added to your page.  In some cases, there are so many additional scripts/styles that some tags get 'pushed down' too far like <meta charset="utf-8"> which is supposed to be in the first 512 bytes of a page.